# Values Match if not being met :S

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

```
function unupdatedRows () {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var formSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var numRows = formSheet.getLastRow();
  var lastRow = formSheet.getRange(numRows,1);
  var lastDate = lastRow.getValue();
  Logger.log(lastUpdate());
  Logger.log(lastDate);
  if (lastDate == lastUpdate()){
    Logger.log("MATCH! Sheet is up to date");

  }
};

Logger output:
[14-06-24 16:12:53:188 EDT] Mon Jun 23 01:50:10 GMT-04:00 2014
[14-06-24 16:12:53:188 EDT] Mon Jun 23 01:50:10 GMT-04:00 2014
```

I should be seeing "MATCH! Sheet is up to date" in the logger too. Why isn't the if statement being met?

Comment: where does lastUpdate() come from ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Avoid checking equality on date objects, they will never be equal (you can use > and < comparison though), do it on their string representation for instance or from any derived value (year, month, day, hours...) or even on their native values (millisec).

Comment: How do I compare second/ms values, sorry if this sounds noobish... would I use a substring or is there code to extract ms?

Comment: .getTime() gives you a value in milliSec, see doc [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp)

Comment: Thankyou VERY much! been looking for that Doc!